# Traefik doesn't pick TLS certificates secrets from the ingress definition in Kubernetes

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, kubernetes

*I have raised this exact query at stackoverflow as well, as, interestingly, "Traefik" and "Kubernetes-Ingress" tags are absent on ServerFault, but present on StackoVerflow.*

When I only add the TLS secret to the Ingress, Traefik serves it's default certificate.

```
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
    ....
  tls:
  - secretName: ingress-mgt-server-keys
```

Only when I mount the secret and add below parameter, does Traefik start serving the real certificate.

> entryPoints.https.tls.certificates

**Are TLS secrets to be define in both, Traefik Ingress and Ingress-controller**? This forces me to repeat the keys as secrets to all the ingress namespaces as well as the ingress-controller namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The TLS Secret isn't needed to be set up in the target (ingress) namespaces.

Only the ingress controller namespace needs the TLS Secret.

Comment: Is better to put the ingress rules in the same namespace of the ingress controller and the tls secret too.

Comment: This is what Traefic documentation says : "In addition to the modified ingress you need to provide the TLS certificate via a Kubernetes secret in the same namespace as the ingress." But following this will mean many duplicate secrets, across namespaces, in my case.